# Simulation with two random walkers on a lattice with periodic boundaries

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics, simulation

I am having some difficulties implementing a Monte Carlo simulation in order to compare the results to analytical calculations. The following code simulates a case with one random walker and a stationary trap. The results from the code below match the analytical calculations. The average walk-length for a 5x5 lattice turns out to be about 31.66, which is correct.

```
stepTypes = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};
pos1 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 2];
While[pos1 != {2, 2}, (*{2,2} is the stationary trap*)
 pos1 = Mod[pos1 + RandomChoice[stepTypes], 5];
 index++
 ]
Print["Walk length is:", index];
index = 0;
```

But when analyzing the same case, only replacing the trap with another random walker. The results dont match at all, they tend to be higher than the analytical and the difference increases hyperbolically as the lattice size grows.

```
stepTypes = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};
pos1 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 2];
pos2 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 2];
While[pos1 != pos2,
  pos1 = Mod[pos1 + RandomChoice[stepTypes], 5];
  pos2 = Mod[pos2 + RandomChoice[stepTypes], 5];

  index++;
  ];
Print["Walk length is:", index];
index = 0;
```

By simulating the first case I was able to tell that my boundary conditions and the random number generation work correct. Not sure if the problem is in the way I synchronize the two walkers' movement? While loop tests the condition after both walkers have moved and increments the walk-length counter once both have moved as well. Any ideas of why the second case does not work? Perhaps it has to do with a subsequent random number generation?

Note: The original code runs this simulation N number of times and computes the average.

```
Analytics:

N     Walker/Trap     Two Walkers
---------------------------------
3     8.99            8.00
4     18.33           22.23
5     31.66           26.10
6     49.24           52.67
7     71.82           56.61
```

Comment: Just skimming, but: if #1 at +5 and #2 at +4, can you end up having #1 go left and #2 go right, so that #1 at +4 and #2 at +5, but #1 and #2 not equal, so your program doesn't realize the two have collided?

Comment: Very Good point. Not sure if that case is supposed to count as a collision, but I will check as soon as I get home. Any simple way to check for it ?

Comment: You can do two checks for equality, one after each step left/right, or you can keep the directions as variables and make sure that the pre and post position of the two walkers is the same (ie, #1 left of #2 in both cases or #1 right of #2 in both cases). If you don't count that as a collision, #1 could pass #2 and continue going to infinity, no?

Comment: The problem is more subtle than I first thought. There only seems to be trouble with square lattices with sides having an even number of points. Limiting your code to odd lattices, I get `{{5, 31.09}, {7, 78.28}, {9, 128.01}, {11, 227.43}, {13, 254.77}, {15, 288.32}}` with the means being taken over 100 iterations. How does that compare to answers you expect? There was no exponential growth of run time as the lattice size increased.

Comment: Yes, i knew about his issue. And the results you got are correct (with a little more iterations they would match the analytic exactly). When computing even sized lattices I ran into infinite loops due to some polarity problems, so the two walkers never meet - not sure how to fix this. Perhaps implementing a check for the case @barrycarter mentioned would fix it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you results match for the case with one walker and a stationary trap. @m_goldberg, not the two walker case (just to clarify)

Comment: @FEARxxx Would you mind including or linking to the analytical results you're talking about so people can check themselves while trying to answer your question?

Comment: @barrycarter That was it. I implemented the logic just by keeping track of previous positions and that did it, the results matched.

Comment: Yes, on even-sized lattices there's a parity problem.  If, for example, walker1 starts on `{0,1}` and the other on `{0,0}` they can never meet, because every step changes both of their y-coordinates by 1, so that `Mod[y1+y2,2]` is a conserved quantity and in this case `=1`, but for them to meet it must be that `y1==y2` and so `Mod[y1+y2,2]==0`.  This can be checked for by simply examining the initial conditions --- no need to run the simulation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy had to do with the way the walkers were subsequently moved. You have to either move synchronously (on separate threads perhaps) or you have to make it check for a specific case where the walkers are exactly one step away and their next step is towards each other. In other words, if they swap positions then there was a collision.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6):

This is not answer, but an extremely long comment.

I find this problem very interesting, but haven't been able to solve it. In my attempts, I developed a tool to visualize the the two-walker random walk. I am posting this tool because I think it might be useful to the OP or anyone else looking this problem for exploring what's going on.

```
steps = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};

simulation[n_, max_] :=
  Module[{index, w1, w2, pos1, pos2},
    index = 0;
    pos1 = RandomInteger[{0, n - 1}, 2];
    pos2 = RandomInteger[{0, n - 1}, 2];
    w1 = {pos1}; w2 = {pos2};
    While[pos1 != pos2 && index <= max,
      AppendTo[w1, pos1 = Mod[pos1 + RandomChoice[steps], n]];
      AppendTo[w2, pos2 = Mod[pos2 + RandomChoice[steps], n]];
      index++];
    {w1, w2}]

path[pts : {{_, _} ...}, color_?ColorQ, r_Real] := 
  {color, 
   {Opacity[.5], Line[Subsequences[pts, {2}]]},
   {Thick, Circle[pts[[1]], r]}, (* start marker *)
   Circle[pts[[-1]], 1.6 r]}     (* end marker *)

visualize[n_, max_: 500] :=
  Module[{w1, w2, r},
    r = .016 (n - 1);
    {w1, w2} = simulation[n, max];
    Graphics[
      {{PointSize[Scaled[.018]], 
         Point @ Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, n - 1}, {0, n - 1}}], 
       1]},                  (* lattice points *)
      {path[w1, Red, 1.4 r], (* red walker path *)
       path[w2, Blue, r]}},  (* blue walker path *)
      PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]]
```

Here are two interesting paths (from a code developer's point-of-view).

```
visualize[9]
```

[image: path9]

The above walk is interesting because the walk ended at the starting point of the blue walker and demonstrates why the marker circles are scaled the way the are.

```
visualize[8]
```

[image: path8]

This one is interesting because it is one of the relatively rare even lattice simulations to come to a successful conclusion.

I really hope someone will come up with an answer to this question soon because I spending too much time on and not getting much out it.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I have found a solution already tho, take a look at the comments above.

Comment: I find this problem interesting, is it possible to post details of your solution @FEARxxx ?

Comment: @thils the discrepancy had to do with the way the walkers were subsequently moved. You have to either move synchronously (on separately threads perhaps) or you have to make it check for a specific case where the walkers are excatly one step away and their next step is towards each other. In other words, if they swap positions then there was a collision.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for a single walker:

```
singleWalker[] := Module[{
    stepTypes = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}},
    pos1 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 2]
    },
Return@Rest@NestWhileList[
    Mod[# + RandomChoice[stepTypes], 5] &,
    pos1,
    # != {2, 2} &
    ];
]
```

Doing `walks = (singleWalker[] & /@ Range[1000]);` and measuring `N@Mean[Length /@ walks]` gives (in my case) 31.013.  I'm not confident I'm measuring exactly the right length (I took `Rest` to count the number of steps, rather than the number of places the walker stood, which is different by 1).

You can also look at `Histogram[Length /@ walks]`.

Here's my (edited to handle the switcheroo/synchronization case as discussed in the comments) code for two walkers:

```
twoWalkers[] := 
  Module[{stepTypes = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}}, 
          pos1 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 2], pos2 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 2]}, 
    Return@Rest@
    NestWhileList[
        Mod[# + {RandomChoice[stepTypes], RandomChoice[stepTypes]}, 5] &,
        {pos1, pos2}, 
        Not@Or[#2[[1]] == #2[[2]], And[#1 == Reverse[#2]]] &, 2];
    ]
```

Then, doing `walks2 = (twoWalkers[] & /@ Range[1000]);` and `N@Mean[Length /@ walks2]` gives about <s>35.47</s> 25.8.

I think the issue is that you are measuring far too few `N`.  Monte Carlo often requires hundreds or thousands of measurements to get a good answer, and you need to convince yourself that you're in the "infinite statistics" limit.  The dramatic hopping around that you get for small `N` suggests that you're not taking a reliable average (ie. that your ensemble is too small).

This is related to the fact that the `Histogram`s are very long-tailed.

Comment: You should have gotten 26.10 and i would say 5000 iterations would be enough. Monte Carlo sims do require a huge amount of statistical data (for it to be accurate) but as that number approaches infinity it gets closer to a specific value, so if after say 5000 iterations you are getting the same mean value, then there is no need to do more. btw as you can read in the comments above, the problem was related to the fact that the walkers didnt move synchronously. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just ran 100000 trajectories and found that two walkers on a 5x5 grid again to be 35.4851.

Comment: The same synchronization problem i had at the very beginning. Look at my answer. Your program does not count for some collisions.

Comment: Ah, I see.  A switch-places step is a collision.

Comment: I implemented the switching case, and got just about 26.